# Confidence vs order in data mining

Tags: data-mining, association-rules, apriori

Is there the relation between confidence and order of association rule when I am applying Apriori algorithm? Or is it dependent on the dataset?

Disclaimer: This is based on a homework question. The dataset we are given has increasing confidence with increasing order of association rule. I wonder if this is true for all the data sets.

Comment: Can you tell us what "order of association rule" means?

Comment: Are you alluding to the downward closure property that considers monotonicity of a measure with respect to the partial order induced by sub/supset relations?

Comment: @Galen: I mean how many items are included in the LHS for the rule when I use Apriori algorithm. I must admit I don't really understand your second comment.

Comment: Left-hand-side (LHS) or which operator (e.g. union) or comparator?

Comment: The "downward closure" property in my second comment pertains to how we can make the search through possible item sets more efficient/feasible. This was covered when I took data mining as a grad student, and I expect it is in most textbooks that cover apriori.